# How do I properly namespace a play application?

Tags: scala, playframework

I started a Play application (my first, if you can't guess that). I kept the standard structure of: app and conf at the project root. assets, controllers, models, and views directly underneath app. Application.scala belongs to the "controllers" package, for example. When I package it it creates a jar called MyAppName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. Obviously this doesn't work if I'm gonna deploy to Nexus.

I tried to refactor all the packages underneath "app" (controllers, models, views) into org.myorg.myappname, and broke it horribly. Any tips on how to properly add namespace to my application?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to set a custom jar name in the sbt build script if that's the only reason you want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand your problem right, but:

**About the artifact to publish to nexus**

The organization and artifact name doesn't really have anything to do with what packages inside it are called. You can set those with the `name` and `organization` settings in `build.sbt`. For example:

```
name := "amazeweb"
organization := "com.mycompany"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

This will work just like setting the corresponding properties in the `pom.xml` of a maven project.

**About the packages**

Having deep namespacing with packages makes sense if your code is going to live together with a lot of other code. For example if you are writing a library, but in Java-land it has become common practice for *everything*.

In a webapp the code is more like the leaf, it will be run, not coded against, so there should never really be a problem with clashing packages. This is the reason play project normally use just a few shallow packages.

Comment: thanks! the organization parameter did the trick. figured it would be very simple (simpler than installing the play2-maven-plugin and managing the build thru maven).